# How to Restrict Amazon EC2 instance access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I had setup amazon EC2 instance on AWS. I can access the instance through my local machine with ssh connection.But i don't want anyone to access my instance even if he has access to my key file how can i restrict this ?

Comment: You can set inbound rule and add your own IP

Comment: May I suggest that you are asking the wrong question.  Asking how to prevent access despite someone having your key-pair is like asking how to prevent access to your website despite having your username and password. While there are barriers you can put up (the IP allow-list suggested), the failure here is that an "attacker" has your key-pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit network access through security groups like @dream-bold said, or you can get rid of the key file altogether and use an alternative like SSM Session Manager or Instance Connect where you can control access via IAM.